# how to update foreign keys in a different table after foreign key element was created in postgres with sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables with a one to many relationship. Parent can have many children, a child can only have one parent.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    children_ids = Column(postgres.ARRAY(Text), server_default=postgres.array("{}"))


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    parent_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey('Parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship("Parent", backref=backref("child", passive_deletes=True, passive_updates=True))
```

I currently create a child entity with the session maker and use `add()` and `commit()`. I then have to manually update the parent entity and push/append the `Child.id` into the `children_ids` column. Is there a way how sqlalchemy can trigger a manual update or do I always have to manually update?

Comment: Don't maintain an array of child id values as a column in the parent table; that's redundant. A one-to-many relationship only requires a foreign key column in the child table. If you want the parent object to contain a list of its children then use a `relationship`. See the tutorial for details.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#working-with-related-objects